# Force failure if Vagrantfile misses environment variable

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a Vagrantfile which I want to use as a common base for different machines. Each machine must have a static IP assigned. This can be achieved using ENV[] in the Vagrantfile.

Though I'd like to force a failure in case for example the environemnt variable IP is not set.

Is there a way to force failure within a Vagrantfile?